# Como encontrar mi ubicación en el mapa, la codificación no produce error, mapa aparece pero sin el boton de ubicación

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng miami = new LatLng(25.7742700, -80.1936600);
        mMap.addMaker(new MarkerOptions().position(miami).title("Marker 
        in Miami"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(miami));
        float zoomLevel = 15;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miami, 
        zoomLevel));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest. 
         permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager. 
         PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,    
         android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
         PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para aprender cómo deben ser formuladas las preguntas y que información debes proporcionar. Una vez entiendas cómo funciona el sitio, ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta con toda la información relevante?

Comment: Gracias por el comentario espero ir mejorando en mis próximas consultas, acabo de editar el código para que sea mas legible y replantee la pregunta esperando que de esta manera puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

1. asegurate tener agregado: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION y ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION en el archivo AndroidManifest.
2. checa los permisos en tiempo de ejecución: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html